# Looking for examples where $f(z)=\operatorname{inv} \int_{0}^{z} g(z)\, dz$ with $f(z)$ entire and $g(z)$ not meromorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion, inverse, elliptic-integrals

I'm looking for examples where $f(z)=\operatorname{inv}\int_{0}^{z} g(z) \, dz$ with $f(z)$ entire and $g(z)$  not meromorphic. For clarity, by $\operatorname{inv}$, I mean the functional inverse. Additional conditions are:

1. $g$ must have a positive radius of convergence around $0$.
2. $f$ is not a polynomial.
3. $f$ is not $\sin(az+b)+c$, $\cos(az+b)+c$, $\tan(az+b)+c$ or their hyperbolic analogues.

Notice that $f(0)=g(0)=0$ must hold.

I know the Lagrange inversion theorem and I know how to express the derivatives in terms of contour integrals. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)

But I'm still stuck. Maybe abelian functions are what I want?

I'm still confused about how things work. I know of course that bounding (all) the derivatives could prove a function to be entire—which is not always easy either?—but that knowledge did not help me so far.

Comment: Notice that f and g relate to the differential equation dy = A(y). Maybe that helps ??

Comment: You use the variable $x$, but also use a lot of complex terminology. Please can use specify the domains? If $x$ can be any complex number then perhaps use $z$. What about $a$, $b$ and $c$? Are they real or complex constants? Perhaps specify: $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ or $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$. (Notice that your first link uses $z$ and $w$ for complex variables.)

Comment: All variables are complex. Since f(x) needs to be entire it is trivial that x is complex. And even if x was real , the need for entire implies the complex plane.

Comment: @FlybyNight I was merely defending my use of $x$. I changed to $z$. For clarity. I did not insult your intelligence. I did not even wrote your name !
I changed and hope you are happy now. Maybe you can remove the downvote now. Or give a good answer.
My oversensitive friend :)

Comment: @FlybyNight I found mick's response to your suggestion to rename a variable perfectly polite.  Your last comment was in bad faith.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks.

Comment: I note that $\sin$ can easily be proved to be entire without investigating its derivatives ; its addition formula shows this !
In analogue I think it is easiest to prove that $f(z)$ is entire if there is an addition formula for $f(z)$.